# Using linq for multiple condition in where

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have a list of conditions and I want to do something like this using linq in C#:

```
var filtred_list = oldList.Where(
    foreach (int condition in conditions) {
        c => c.attribut == condition;
    }
);
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, converting where statement as below is enough:

```
var filtred_list = oldList.Where(
        c => conditions.Contains(c.attribut);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IEnumerable<T>.Contains(T)` method:

```
var filtred_list = oldList.Where(c => conditions.Contains(c.attribut));
```

or

```
var filtred_list = from o in oldList
                   where conditions.Contains(o.attribut)
                   select o;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtred_list = oldList.Where(x => conditions.Any(c => c.attribut == x));
```